# Question about Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a question about Modular Arithmetic Cryptography.

How do I calculate $(-5)^{-3}$ or $(-5)^{-4}$ (even or uneven exponent)?

What do I have to do first here ? I can’t ignore the minus?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(-5)^(-x) = (-5)^((-1)*x) = ((-5)[^(-1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse))^x

The above link also has a good "Computation" section.

Comment: For example i want to Calculate (-5)^-3 mod 19
I have to Calculate (-5)^-1 mod 19 = 15
and then 15^3 mod 19 ?

Comment: Yes. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​